# From a certain number of rows with the same primary key, how do I select the ones with the highest value in a certain column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a Students table and a Grades table.

- **Students** has columns *student_id(primary key), name, date_of_birth, address, email,* and *level*.
- **Grades** has columns *student_id(primary/foreign key), course_id(primary/foreign key),* and *grade*.

"Grades" looks like this:

```
student_id|course_id|grade
===========================
    1     |    1    |   A
    1     |    2    |   B
    1     |    3    |   A
    3     |    1    |   F
    3     |    3    |   C
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

This isn't the whole table, but you get the gist. I'm trying to write a query which SELECTS the name of a student and that student's highest grade. As I'm new to SQL this one is a little confusing for me. My attempt so far is this:

```
SELECT "Students".name, "Grades".grade FROM "Students" INNER JOIN
"Grades" ON "Students".student_id = "Grades".student_id GROUP BY name, 
grade HAVING MIN(grade) <= 'F';
```

It's wrong, and I know why, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You have `Students` and `Grades`, not `Enroll` like it pops up in your code.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter whoops, fixed it. It's called Enroll in my code, but I changed it here to Grades for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Students.name, min(Enroll.grade)  
  FROM Students 
 INNER JOIN Enroll 
    ON Students.student_id = Enroll.student_id 
 GROUP BY name,
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I select **the ones with the highest value** in a certain column?

Bold emphasis mine.

`GROUP BY` is good to get the maximum for a single column. To get the ***rows*** with the maximum, you'd have to do more.

The simple solution in Postgres to get ***one*** row per student is with [`DISTINCT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564):

```
SELECT *
FROM   students s
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (student_id) *
   FROM   grades
   ORDER  BY student_id, grade
   ) g USING (student_id);
```

The *lowest* happens to be the "highest" grade here.
To get `the ones with the highest value` (possible ***plural***), use the window function [**`rank()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM   students s
JOIN  (
   SELECT *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY grade) AS rnk
   FROM   grades
   ) g USING (student_id)
WHERE  g.rnk = 1;
```